# Why does `<input type='date' />` and `<input type='time' />` have onchange issues in Firefox? Or am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, html, css

It seems that Firefox desktop only runs a change Event upon focus, which does not occur from simply closing `<input type='date' />` or `<input type='time' />`. Somehow this problem is not reproducible using Stack Overflow, even with Firefox *(If you know why...do tell)*. But if you run the code on localhost, using Firefox, you will see it seems to work every other time. I believe this is because Firefox will refocus on a previously focused Element when the page is reloaded.

So, what do I mean by "work"? When you hit the close button, if the value is `=== ''`, that should get `console.log()`ed, as you can see from the code I wrote below. Sometimes it does not get logged and the value changes back to empty, so it doesn't work. Change Event fails to fire using Firefox Quantum 67.0 (64-bit).

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, I, DateTime; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
DateTime = function(dateElement, timeElement, dateInstance){
  var t = this;
  this.dateElement = dateElement; this.timeElement = timeElement;
  this.date = dateInstance instanceof Date ? dateInstance : new Date;
  this.dateValue = function(dateInstance){
    if(dateInstance instanceof Date)this.date = dateInstance;
    var dt = this.date;
    return dt.getFullYear()+'-'+(dt.getMonth()+1).toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1')+'-'+dt.getDate().toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1');
  }
  this.showDate = function(dateInstance){
    this.dateElement.value = this.dateValue(dateInstance);
    return this;
  }
  this.timeValue = function(dateInstance){
    if(dateInstance instanceof Date)this.date = dateInstance;
    var dt = this.date;
    return dt.getHours().toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1')+':'+dt.getMinutes().toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, '0$1');
  }
  this.showTime = function(dateInstance){
    this.timeElement.value = this.timeValue(dateInstance);
    return this;
  }
  this.showDate().showTime();
  this.dateChange = function(changeFunc, noDateFunc){
    this.dateElement.onchange = function(){
      var v = this.value;
      if(v === ''){
        console.log("t.dateElement.value === ''");
        if(noDateFunc)t.showDate(noDateFunc(t));
      }
      else{
        var s = t.timeElement.value;
        if(s === '')s = t.timeValue(new Date);
        t.date = new Date(v+' '+s);
      }
      changeFunc(t.date, t);
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.timeChange = function(changeFunc, noTimeFunc){
    this.timeElement.onchange = function(){
      var v = this.value;
      if(v === ''){
        console.log("t.timeElement.value === ''");
        if(noTimeFunc)t.showTime(noTimeFunc(t));
      }
      else{
        var s = t.dateElement.value;
        if(s === '')s = t.dateValue(new Date);
        t.date = new Date(s+' '+v);
      }
      changeFunc(t.date, t);
    }
    return this;
  }
}
var hourTest = function(){
    return new Date(Date.now()+3600000);
  }
var dt = new DateTime(I('edit_date'), I('edit_time'), hourTest());
dt.dateChange(function(dateResult){
  console.log(dateResult.toString());
}, hourTest).timeChange(function(timeResult){
  console.log(timeResult.toString());
}, hourTest);
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.js */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#content{
  padding:7px;
}
label,input{
  font:22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
label{
  display:block; height:26px; font-weight:bold; margin:7px 0 4px; float:left;
}
input{
   width:100%; height:38px; background:#fff; color:#000; padding:5px; border:1px solid #0b0; float:left;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <label for='edit_date'>Notify Date</label><input class='yes' id='edit_date' type='date' />
    <label for='edit_time'>Notify Time</label><input class='yes' id='edit_time' type='time' />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to guarantee that a change Event occurred, because it seems without focusing on the date or time, it may just decide not to fire?

Comment: That doesn't seem to happen with me

Comment: Can you try to reformulate your question please? That's very not clear what is the actual problem you are facing + having this whole code block not even reproducing the error makes it even less readable. Can you set a real [MCVE]? Are you facing this issue only on reload of the page (as in the field is set automatically by the browser)? And if it's something else, then how do you perform the change that should trigger this event if not when focusing the element?

Comment: Did you copy the code and paste into your localhost, then test it?

Comment: A simple example like `<input type="date" onchange="console.log(this.value)">` behaves [*as described on MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event). Copying the OP code and running locally shows the same behaviour. Voting to close as off–topic as the OP hasn't included code to show that it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: works identically in firefox as it does in chrome

Comment: So if you close it without other focus, it should not fire the change event? Seems crazy, since a change did occur. I'm 1000% sure this is a bug now.

Comment: `@RobG`, you must not have tested this. Closing should create a change Event, if the value has changed, which it has.

Comment: Have you tried listening for the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) instead?

Comment: Btw, I tried this in Firefox on macos (66.0.3 and 67.0), running from a local file, and I'm seeing console.log's every time the input changes (without focus changing). Also, what do you mean by "close button"?

Comment: I mean the x on the right. I'm using Firefox Quantum 67.0 (64-bit). `@Cully`, that worked, so if you put that as your answer I will give you the points. It's still a bug since the change occurred though.

Comment: @StackSlave I posted an answer. If you can think of a way to improve it for people finding the answer in the future, leave a comment.

Comment: @StackSlave Also, I tried clicking the "x" button and I see your console message, and the date changes to the value your `hourTest` function provides.

Comment: Are you running this from a file (e.g. `file://`) or from a server on localhost?

Comment: I also tried on a live server. It's not ftp.

Comment: Re "*you must not have tested this*". Either you didn't read "*running locally shows the same behaviour*" or you don't believe what I wrote. Not a good start to a conversation. You've accepted Cully's answer but it doesn't answer your question (*Is there any way to guarantee that a change Event occurred*), or tell you why you get your apparently aberrant behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if what you're seeing is a bug or not, but if you can't figure out a solution to the issue with the `change` event, you could try listening for the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) instead.

> The input event is fired every time the value of the element changes. This is unlike the change event, which only fires when the value is committed, such as by pressing the enter key, selecting a value from a list of options, and the like.

From OP's comments, to fix the issue, change these lines from:

```
this.dateElement.onchange = function(){
```

```
this.timeElement.onchange = function(){
```

to:

```
this.dateElement.oninput = function(){
```

```
this.timeElement.oninput = function(){
```

Comment: `.onchange` simply got changed to `.oninput` and it works!

Comment: @StackSlave I updated the answer with the changes. Does that look right?

Comment: Yeah, that drove me near nuts, since it was working on my Stack Overflow mock-up *(before I posted)*, but not on my Browser by itself.

Comment: Well, glad you found a workaround if not a solution :)

Comment: Still makes no sense to me that `.onchange` works on Stack Overflow with the exact same Browser. MKUltra!